# Help with solving a system of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need help with solving this system of differential equations:
 $$ \dot{x}= \begin{pmatrix} -1 & -1 \\ -1 & -1\end{pmatrix}  x+ e^{-2t} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} $$

I think it's solvable with the method of variation of parameters.
But apart from calculating the Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors I don't know how to proceed. I've searched for similar tasks, but could't find anthing that I can understand. I would be very greatful if you can tell me what to do :-) !!

Comment: It's always better to post what you tried ..you get more answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\dot{X}= \begin{pmatrix} -1 & -1 \\ -1 & -1\end{pmatrix}  X+ e^{-2t} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

Rewrite both equations with $x(t),y(t),\, X=\pmatrix {x(t) \\ y(t)}$
$$
\begin{cases}
x'=-x-y+e^{-2t} \\
y'=-x-y
\end{cases}
$$

Then you can deduce that
$$y'-x'=-e^{-2t}$$
Integrate
$$\implies y(t)=x(t)+\frac 12e^{-2t}+K$$
Plug that in this equation and solve for $x(t)$ the differential equation
$$x'=-x-y+e^{-2t}$$
$$\implies x'=-2x+\frac 12e^{-2t}-K$$
$$......$$
Can you take it from there ?

Comment: thank you alot !! ..now it makes more sense to me..what i get for $ x(t)= (\frac{1}{2} +k) e^{-2t} $

Comment: yw @pastapesto23 ...